# (Linux) PDO cannot find the MySQL driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So basically I have been always developing with PHP under Windows with the WAMP package and I never had any trouble.

Now, I am trying to transition to Linux (Mint). Everything is well, except for the PDO extension which cannot find the MySQL driver. In fact, it states not having any available drivers at all.

First, I installed Apache:

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

Then, PHP:

`sudo apt-get install php5`

MySQL for PHP (I am not exactly sure this was required):

`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

Finally, the command line interface for PHP:

`sudo apt-get install php5-cli`

Note that I had installed MySQL a while ago for other purposes.

Everything else is working well. The server starts, runs, executes scripts. I am also able to create an instance of PDO, but then it throws a PDOException stating that it cannot find the MySQL driver. The code is typical of a PDO initialization :

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;db=testdb", "root", "");
```

I looked at the `phpinfo()` and for the value **PDO** I see *no drivers*. However, I see the line **MySQL driver for PDO** followed by the names of its authors, but I cannot tell if it guarantees the presence of the driver. Notice that I also see the authors of all the other drivers (SQLite, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc.).

The command `php -m` (which, according to the `php --help`, lists all modules compiled with PHP) also clearly indicates that both **PDO** and **pdo_mysql** are installed.

My search returned a lot of results about the extensions `pdo.so` and `pdo-mysql.so`. I have been trying to reference them into the `php.ini` file without success. It would probably have a higher chance of success if I actually had these files, but so far I have been unable to find them.

So, here we are, about five hours later, with me being completely stuck.

Thank you.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install pdo-mysql`

Comment: Try using the MySQLnd driver instead.  `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`.  This should replace `php5-mysql`.